# plot data grouped by year

Tags: r, plot, zoo

I'm trying to create a plot of temperatures but I can't aggregate the data by year. 
My data comes in this form:

```
02-2012 7.2
02-2013 7.2
02-2010 7.9
02-2011 9.8
03-2013 10.7
03-2010 13.1
03-2012 18.5
03-2011 13.7
02-2003 9.2
...
```

containing all the months between Jan 2000 and Dec 2013. I've loaded the data with zoo:

```
f <- function(x) as.yearmon(format(x), "%m-%Y")
temp <- read.zoo(file="results.tsv", FUN = f)
```

Plotting the temp var I obtain a plot with X axis going from Jan 2000 to Dec 2013, but what I'd like to have is a plot where the X axis goes from Jan to Dec and the temperatures of every year are plotted as a separate line. Any hint?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: aggregate considering a function? mean? max? min? sd?

Comment: probably "grouped" is not the right term, sorry. What I meant was that I want to show all the data, but every year should be plotted as a separate line.

Comment: Ok, I think you got the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want to separate out the date into it's year and month components:

```
names(temp) <- c("date","temperature")
tmpSplit <- strsplit(temp$date, "-")
temp$month <- sapply(tmpSplit, "[", 1)
temp$year <- sapply(tmpSplit, "[", 2)
```

Then, my preference would be to use the ggplot2 package to plot your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(x=month, y=temperature, group=year)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: I'd add `geom_line(aes(colour = year)` to get it mapped.

Comment: Calling the first strsplit returns me the error: Error in `$.zoo`(temp, date) : not possible for univariate zoo series. I've tried also using read.csv instead of read.zoo, but strsplit returns: Error in strsplit(temp$date, "-") : non-character argument.

Comment: You may also use `format` to extract relevant parts of a `yearmon` object. `ym <- as.yearmon("04-2014", format = "%m-%Y")`; `format(ym, "%Y")`; `format(ym, "%m")`

Comment: Ok, I've used the read.csv instead of read.zoo and the formatter of yearmon and it works perfectly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here are several approaches. First set up the data.  Note the simplification in `read.zoo`.

```
library(zoo)
temp <- read.zoo("results.tsv", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m-%Y")
```

In addition to the plots below there is `monthplot` in the base of R (stats package). It does not appear to work with `as.ts(temp)` if `temp` is the subset of data provided in the question but if the actual data looks more like those in the examples of `?monthplot` then it would work.

**1) ggplot2**

Create a data.frame `DF` with columns for the month, year and value.  `cycle` can get the month numbers and format with a format of `%Y` can give the years.
Note that we want the years to be a factor which data frame makes them as the result of format being character.  Finally create the plot using ggplot2 or lattice:

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- data.frame(Month = coredata(cycle(temp)), 
                 Year = format(index(temp), "%Y"),
                 Value = coredata(temp))

ggplot(DF, aes(Month, Value, col = Year)) + 
           geom_line() + 
           scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image: ggplot2 screenshot]

**2) lattice** With DF from 2) this would work:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Value ~ Month, DF, group = Year, type = "l", auto = TRUE)
```

[image: xyplot screenshot]

**REVISED** Added solutions and additional commentary.